# How to display file size on view ? [Shrine Gem - Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

I have these association, and i'm using shrine gem to upload file.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord 
  include ImageUploader[:cover_image]
  has_many :albums, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums, 
end

class Album, < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :photos, 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, 
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord 
  include ImageUploader[:image]
  belongs_to :album   
end
```

Project Controller

```
def show
  @project = Project.includes(albums: :photos).find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.js # show.js.erb
     format.json { render json: @project }
   end
end
```

I want to display project with all its association and its details (file size, filename etc) in Project#show view. 
I can display the size for Project cover image with @project.cover_image.size but when i'm using it for photo.image.size throws error

```
<p>
  <%= @project.name %>
  <%= @project.cover_image.size %> #this return the size 868923  
<p>

<% @project.albums.each do |album| %>
   <%= album.name %>
   <% album.photos.each do |photo| %>
       <%= photo.image.size %>  # this throws error !undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: What error does `photo.image.size` throw?

Comment: @janko-m hi.. i'm adding more details in the questions.

Comment: the error was !undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Then it means that you have a Photo record without an attached image. If that's unexpected, you have to figure out how that happened. If it is expected, then you can for example just use the safe navigation operator: `photo.image&.size`.

Comment: photo.image&.size works! How ever i'm not really sure what "photo record without an attached image" means and what cause it to happen. I guess i have to research about it later. Still learning rails. :) Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```
<%= image_tag @photo.image_url(:small) if @photo.image %>
```